# flutter_native_admob doesn't support null safety, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

i've upgraded the sdk , then i add some dependencies but i got some problems about null safety.

`Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.2.

Because Myapp depends on flutter_native_admob >=0.1.1+1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
Process finished with exit code 1`